# How to ignore npm run errors and keep going on Travis-CI?

Tags: npm, config, travis-ci

I have stage in Travis config that launch `npm run build` where the build is a script converting ts -> js. Locally, it returns two errors that doesn't matter anything, I can run a server anyway. But, these errors stop Travis moving on and fails.

```
    - stage: "Build front"
      before_script:
        - cd front
        - npm install
        - npm run build
```

The error:

```
...
[0] npm run build:client exited with code 0
build/setupProdServer.ts(6,20): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../src/vue-ssr-server-bundle.json'.
build/setupProdServer.ts(7,28): error TS2307: Cannot find module '../src/vue-ssr-client-manifest.json'.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 2
...
```

I tried add

```
allow-failures:
        - node
        - npm
```

and it not helped.

I need Travis ignore these errors and move to the next stage.

What kind of commands or parameters in Travis will solve it?

Comment: Please add those error outputs. Without them we can be unable to help.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just add `|| true`:

`- npm run build || true`

Comment: Nice hack. I wonder why using  `npm run build 2>&1` does not work on travis as well as this one?